# Declaring local variables as final without initializer and assigning in if-statement

Tags: java, eclipse, variables, declaration, final

I just made a small code change to silence a FindBugs warning which required moving some code to an anonymous inner class. In order to access some variables, I had to declare those as `final`. So this is the code snippet after the change:

```
final File[] libPath; // libPath is final but assignment takes place later
if (libraryPath != null) {
    libPath = pathToFiles(libraryPath);
} else {
    libPath = new File[0];
}
```

This compiles just fine with language set to Java 6 in current Eclipse (Version 3.7.1). However I'm quite sure this used to give an error in some previous version. Seems the compiler accepts this construct when it can determine that there will be.

My question is: is this legal in Java 6 or is it something that now works due to a side effect of Java 7 support being added to eclipse 3.7.1? We have seen such side effects with certain usage of generics that works in 3.7.1 but didn't compile in 3.7.0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was allowed and worked fine since Java 1.1 and will not get you in trouble with other compilers or IDEs.

It is standard behaviour in Java and was first formally specified in the [Java Language Specification 2nd Edition](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/typesValues.doc.html#10931).

Comment: From the many correct answers pointing to the language specification I will accept this one since you were the first to answer.

Answer (score 14):

this is ok. it is called *blank final*

quote from wiki:

> A final variable can only be initialized once, either via an
>   initializer or an assignment statement. It need not be initialized at
>   the point of declaration: this is called a "blank final" variable. A
>   blank final instance variable of a class must be definitely assigned
>   at the end of every constructor of the class in which it is declared;
>   similarly, a blank final static variable must be definitely assigned
>   in a static initializer of the class in which it is declared:
>   otherwise, a compile-time error occurs in both cases. [4] (Note: If
>   the variable is a reference, this means that the variable cannot be
>   re-bound to reference another object. But the object that it
>   references is still mutable, if it was originally mutable.)
>
> ***Blank final***
>
> The blank final, which was introduced in Java 1.1, is a final variable
>   whose declaration lacks an initializer. [5][6] A blank final can only
>   be assigned once and must be unassigned when an assignment occurs. In
>   order to do this, a Java compiler runs a flow analysis to ensure that,
>   for every assignment to a blank final variable, the variable is
>   definitely unassigned before the assignment; otherwise a compile-time
>   error occurs.[7]
>
> In general, a Java compiler will ensure that the blank final is not
>   used until it is assigned a value and that once assigned a value, the
>   now final variable cannot be reassigned another value.[8]

link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_%28Java%29

Comment: Wow, I thought I knew all of Java's syntax at least, thanks for explaining this new wrinkle.

Answer (score 1):

Java Language Specification contains a whole chapter dedicated to this behaviour ([Chapter 16 
Definite Assignment](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/defAssign.html)).

This behaviour is thoroughly defined, so that I think you misinterpret something when you say that used to produce an error in previous versions.

Answer (score 0):

It's fine. The variable does not have a value, and is assigned only once. It would fail if you have given it a `null` value initially.

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly suggest to use this code instead:

```
final File[] libPath = ibraryPath == null ? new File[0] : pathToFiles(libraryPath);
```

This does not depend on any compiler version, but is 100% supported Java with a clear meaning.

Comment: It's a matter of taste, maybe. But I prefer it, because expressions stay expressions and are not needlessly converted into statements. This is also a language construct that is present in almost every language since at least C, so he who can't read it should maybe quit his job rather sooner than later.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this will work and is safe to use in all java versions I've seen (1.3+).

**final** means that you cannot change the value of the object once it has been initialized, if you placed a null upon declaration it would've broke.